# git - how to set a remote branch out of a branch in upstream?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Use case - I have a code base on github, which has several branches.
e.g. developer, integration, regression, production, etc.
I usually use this command to add remote branch: `git remote add upstream <repo link>.git`

So, `git remote -v` shows as below:

```
upstream        <repo link>.git (fetch)
upstream        <repo link>.git (push)
```

but if remote has a branch then what command should I use to set to that branch to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `git fetch` or `git pull` to bring up the remote changes including new branches.

Run `git branch -a` to list down all the remote branches.

To move or work with fetched remote branch use

```
Syntax: git checkout -t remotes/upstream/branchname
Example: git checkout -t remotes/origin/branchname
```

Here -t will create local branch with upstream branch mapping. So the next push/pull/fetch operation will not ask you to run `git branch --set-upstream-to` sometime.

Answer (score 0):

To make a new remote branch to local, you can use `git fetch`.

After that, you will find the branch by `git branch -a`.

If you want to work on the new branch, just use `git checkout branchname`.